# fm application in eclipse for android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have got a problem in the line below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

The error says that  tag appears after  tag.
But in tutorial,the above line is mentioned after application tag and the application is correct.
How to solve the error?

Comment: FSM save us  ... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) is how the `Manifest` structure should look. If you have your `<uses-permission>` tag inside the `<application>` tag, move it out from there.

That said, you should post more code and/or information (*but only relevant parts!*) or it will be neigh impossible to find the right solution without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

before `<application>` tag.